# Will we move questions from other S.E sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, stackexchange

There are several questions related to computer graphics on Stack Exchange sites, mainly on Stack Overflow and Game Development.
I saw in the past questions being moved from an S.E site to a more relevant one, but I do not know what are the rules and etiquette for this kind of procedures.
Will we be able to move a CG question to our site ? Is it only possible when the question has not yet been answered maybe ?
I would also think that this cannot be done until cg.se becomes a "full member" site. Where can we find information about this ?

Comment: Migration to beta sites is generally discouraged. Also see this MSE post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247251/201409

Comment: Besides that, questions will only be migrated, if it is off-topic on the site it is posted on. So all open questions on said sites will remain there as they apparently are on-topic. There is also a [FAQ question on Meta SE about migration](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). But I've also seen a few questions been migrated to Startups SE, even though the site is still in public beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless a question has been deemed *off topic* on the other site, you should ***not*** be soliciting or annexing content from another site to build this one.

Consider that you are very likely orphaning content if original author(s) do not have an account here, and moving a post is essentially *removing* any reputation the original author has earned on their own site.

[**Respect the Community, Your Own and Others'**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)